# How to correctly encode commas in email display name?

Tags: email, zend-framework2

I have a similar problem to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8642845/erroneous-email-receiver-display-when-using-german-umlauts-and-a-comma-in-name), but could not find any useful information in the answers.

I'm trying to send an email to a recipient with a display name `Lastname, firstname` using the Quoted-Printable encoding. The exact header, as seen in the source of the received email, is:

```
To: =?UTF-8?Q?"Lastname,=20firstname"?= <email@example.com>
```

However, Outlook displays it like this:

[image: Outlook recipient display]

Effectively interpreting the comma as a separator between recipients, even though it's enclosed in a Quoted-Printable encoding.

When there is no comma, the header is properly interpreted.

Am I doing something wrong, or is it impossible to use commas in a [display-name](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.4)?

*Note: I'm currently using Amazon SES and the ZF2 `Zend\Mail` component, but the tools should not matter, I'm only interested in the correct header format and will adjust my tools or code accordingly.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is not correct behavior as far as I can tell, but the workaround should be obvious: QP-encode the comma. The double quotes are redundant and should be omitted:

```
From: =?UTF-8?q?Lastname=2C_Firstname?= <email@example.com>
```

(As such, it is obviously insane to put the last name first; but e.g. Outlook connected to Active Directory seems to insist on this silly anti-convention.)

Comment: Indeed, it looks like a bug in this library. That makes me notice that PHP's [quoted_printable_encode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.quoted-printable-encode.php) does not encode commas or spaces, either. Anyway, I think I will switch to base64 encoding and live happy!

Comment: QP by itself does not mandate this; the [RFC2047](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2047.txt) encoding has a few additional requirements of its own.